# Using regex function in a while loop

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink, while-loop, preg-match

I have a function that gets a specific link from a specific website, and it works, but the problem starts when I try to use this function in a while loop. When I tried that, the links length starts to stack up for some reason.

```
function getLinks($link) {

$link1 = $link;
$content = file_get_contents($link1);

$content = str_replace("<", "", $content);
$content = str_replace(">", "", $content);

preg_match("~previous page.+?next page~i", $content, $match);
preg_match("~\"(/.+?)\"~i", $match[0], $match);
$link2 = "https://en.wiktionary.org".$match[1];

echo $link1."<br>";
echo $link2."<br>";

return $link2;

}


$firstLink = getLinks("https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:English_verbs&pagefrom=AUTOPILOT%0Aautopilot#mw-pages");
```

**Result firstLink = getLinks():**

```
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:English_verbs&pagefrom=AUTOPILOT%0Aautopilot#mw-pages
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:English_verbs&pagefrom=BAGSIE%0Abagsie#mw-pages
```

^--- See how it works fine when it's like this? Then when I put it in a while loop:

```
$count = 0; 
while ($count < 5) {

$count++;
$firstLink = getLinks($firstLink);

}
```

The results comes up totally messed up, and the links started to stack up upon each other, like so:

```
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:English_verbs&pagefrom=AUTOPILOT%0Aautopilot#mw-pages
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:English_verbs&pagefrom=BAGSIE%0Abagsie#mw-pages
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:English_verbs&pagefrom=BAGSIE%0Abagsie#mw-pages
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:English_verbs&amp%3Bpagefrom=BAGSIE%0Abagsie&pagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify#mw-pages
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:English_verbs&amp%3Bpagefrom=BAGSIE%0Abagsie&pagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify#mw-pages
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:English_verbs&amp%3Bamp%3Bpagefrom=BAGSIE%0Abagsie&amp%3Bpagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify&pagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify#mw-pages
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:English_verbs&amp%3Bamp%3Bpagefrom=BAGSIE%0Abagsie&amp%3Bpagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify&pagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify#mw-pages
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:English_verbs&amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bpagefrom=BAGSIE%0Abagsie&amp%3Bamp%3Bpagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify&amp%3Bpagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify&pagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify#mw-pages
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:English_verbs&amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bpagefrom=BAGSIE%0Abagsie&amp%3Bamp%3Bpagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify&amp%3Bpagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify&pagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify#mw-pages
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:English_verbs&amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bpagefrom=BAGSIE%0Abagsie&amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bpagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify&amp%3Bamp%3Bpagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify&amp%3Bpagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify&pagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify#mw-pages
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:English_verbs&amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bpagefrom=BAGSIE%0Abagsie&amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bpagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify&amp%3Bamp%3Bpagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify&amp%3Bpagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify&pagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify#mw-pages
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:English_verbs&amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bpagefrom=BAGSIE%0Abagsie&amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bpagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify&amp%3Bamp%3Bamp%3Bpagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify&amp%3Bamp%3Bpagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify&amp%3Bpagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify&pagefrom=ACETIFY%0Aacetify#mw-pages
```

This is driving me insane, so if anyone know what I did wrong, please, please tell me. Thank you.

**Regular function in while loop:**

```
function addOne($num) {

echo $num."<br>";   
$num++;
return $num;    

}

$num = 0;
$count = 0;
while ($count < 5) {

$count++;
$num = addOne($num);    

}
```

^---Works just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with HTML entities. I've re-wrote the function to address that issue, repeated URLs and to make it more efficient. You call it with a depth parameter, which would in your case be your while's max.

```
function getLinks($linkd, $depth, $checked=array()) {

if(!is_array($linkd)) $linkd=array($linkd);
    foreach($linkd as $link)
    {
        if(isset($checked[$link])) continue;
        $link1 = $link;
        $content = file_get_contents($link1);

        $content = str_replace("<", "", $content);
        $content = str_replace(">", "", $content);

        preg_match("~previous page.+?next page~i", $content, $match);
        preg_match("~\"(/.+?)\"~i", $match[0], $match);
        $link2 = "https://en.wiktionary.org".$match[1];

        echo $link1."<br>";
        echo $link2."<br>";

        $checked[$link] = true;

        if($depth>0)
        {
            $depth--;
            return getLinks(html_entity_decode($link2), $depth, $checked);
        }
        else
        {
            return $link2;
        }

    }
}


$firstLink = "https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:English_verbs&pagefrom=AUTOPILOT%0Aautopilot#mw-pages";

$firstLink = getLinks($firstLink, 5);
```

Comment: The website has a next page link, and basically, my function is accessing the next page link, and returning the next page's link to the variable $firstLink. Then, it uses $firstLink to get the next page's link on THAT page, and it repeats that 5 times.

Comment: So it gets the link of page1, go to page1, gets the link of page2, go to page2, gets the link of page3, go to page3, and on and on.

Comment: I don't think you're right. A regular function in a while loop, works just fine. Take a look at the section "Regular function in while loop:", that I just updated above.

Comment: It doesn't work. Have you tested it yet? I already tested it, and it doesn't.

Comment: Edited the code again. IT works now. Thanks for your downvote and rudeness though, you rock ;)

Comment: Ah. Upvoted, and accepted. I apologize for downvoting. Was really pissed at myself, and just plain frustrated at forcing it to work for hours and not understanding why it doesn't work.

Comment: I still don't really understand why it doesn't work, by the way, but as long as it works, I guess it's cool.

Comment: You can try to add the `html_entity_decode` function I added and see if it works

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH! So, today, I needed to use something like this again, and I really wanted to figure out an easier way to figure just what the hell went wrong. And guess what? I used the original code, and replaced the &amp; with &, and it works! I feel terrible.